# Why isn't my throttled requestAnimationFrame running 60FPS on my 144hz monitor?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, requestanimationframe

I want to make my requestAnimationFrame run 60FPS regardless of monitors refresh rate so the game would run at the same speed on every monitor. 
Although it seems to work, when I try using chrome DevTools performance tab I can see the **FPS being like -> 48, 72, 48, 72....**

**Here is my throttled version of rAF**

```
let start;
let elapsed;
function startAnimating(timestamp) {
    const fpsInterval = 1000 / 60;

    if (start === undefined) {
        start = timestamp
    }

    elapsed = timestamp - start;


    if (elapsed >= fpsInterval) {
       start = timestamp - (elapsed % fpsInterval);
       move();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(startAnimating);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TL;DR is, `requestAnimationFrame()` runs whenever it feels like. You can't really throttle it. If you want to try to do that, you should use `setTimeout()` or `setInternal()` instead. They'll be called closer to your throttled rate, usually +/- 4ms.

Or you can do what you're doing, which is throttle when you take action, if you want. You'll see in DevTools whatever `requestAnimationFrame()` is being called at, but your function would only do the `move()` at 60FPS, or whatever rate best lines up with it. Though, this can create some clunkiness, since you may end up with much slower effective FPSthan what you want, if the intervals between each call by `requestAnimationFrame()` don't line up well with your target FPS.

Usually a better approach is instead scale all of your changes, such as movement, by the delta of your time since the last call:

```
 let lastTime = Date.now();
 
 function startAnimating() {
   const now = Date.now();
   const delta = now - lastTime;
   lastTime = now;

   move(delta); // delta is the ms since the last call

   requestAnimationFrame(delta);
 }

 function move(delta) {
   character.moveBy(speedInPxPerSecond * (delta / 1000));
 }

 startAnimating();
```

So, if you want your character to move 100px a second, if you multiply that 100 by `delta / 1000`, you end up with a character that moves exactly (or very, very nearly exactly) 100px a second, regardless if your FPS is 10, 30, 60, or 1000.

Answer (score 1):

> ...so the game would run at the same speed on every monitor.

With respect, that's not the best way to do that. (It's not just you, people make this mistake all the time. :-) ) Your game should run at the same speed regardless of whether your `rAF` callbacks are done at 30Hz, 60Hz, 144Hz, or whatever. The way animation and time-based game logic should be written is to look at the current time as of the callback and figure out what to render at that moment. The `rAF` callbacks should **not** be what drives the clock of the game. That should be based on an actual clock (for instance, `Date.now()` or `performance.now()`).

For example, here's a simple animation done incorrectly (based on calls to `rAF`). Aside from the fact that it will run at the wrong speed if your refresh rate is not 60Hz, the browser gets busy for a minute and can't update the screen:

```js
// Make the block go left to right in five seconds
// 5sec = 5,000ms. 5sec at 60Hz is 300 callbacks
// 100% / 300 = 0.333333334% per callback.
const block = document.getElementById("block");
let start = Date.now();
updateBlock();

let timerHandle = 0;
busyBrowser();

function busyBrowser() {
    timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      const stop = Date.now() + 100;
      while (Date.now() < stop); // NEVER DO THIS FOR REAL
      busyBrowser();
    }, 230);
}
function updateBlock() {
    let left = parseFloat(block.style.left || "0");
    left = Math.min(100, left + 0.333333334);
    block.style.left = left + "%";
    if (left === 100) {
        console.log(`Done after ${(Date.now() - start) / 1000} seconds`);
        clearInterval(timerHandle);
    } else {
        requestAnimationFrame(updateBlock);
    }
}
```

```css
#channel {
    position: relative;
    height: 1rem;
}
#block {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
Should take five seconds to go left to right.
<div id="channel">
<div id="block">X</div>
</div>
```

On my system with a 100Hz refresh rate, that takes four seconds, because it's wrong in two ways:

1. My refresh rate is 100Hz, not 60Hz, but the code assumes it's 60Hz.
2. There were times when the browser was busy doing "other things" (my busy loop) and couldn't call `rAF`.

The only reason it's four seconds is the delays (#2); without them, it's three seconds.

Instead, the code in `rAF` should look at what the time is, and render based on where things should be at that time:

```js
// Make the block go left to right in five seconds
// 5sec = 5,000ms. 5sec at 60Hz is 300 callbacks
// 100% / 300 = 0.333333334% per callback.
const block = document.getElementById("block");
let start = Date.now();
let stop = start + 5000;
updateBlock();
let timerHandle = 0;
busyBrowser();

function busyBrowser() {
    timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      const stop = Date.now() + 100;
      while (Date.now() < stop); // NEVER DO THIS FOR REAL
      busyBrowser();
    }, 230);
}
function updateBlock() {
    const elapsed = Date.now() - start;
    let left = Math.min(
        100,
        elapsed * 0.02 // 100 / 5000 = 0.2% per ms
    );
    block.style.left = left + "%";
    if (left === 100) {
        console.log(`Done after ${elapsed / 1000} seconds`);
        clearInterval(timerHandle);
    } else {
        requestAnimationFrame(updateBlock);
    }
}
```

```css
#channel {
    position: relative;
    height: 1rem;
}
#block {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
Should take five seconds to go left to right.
<div id="channel">
<div id="block">X</div>
</div>
```

That finishes in five seconds on my machine, despite my faster refresh rate and the browser being intermittently busy.